# .NET MAUI - JSON file opens from path in iOS debug build but not Mac Catalyst debug build

Tags: ios, .net, filestream, maui, mac-catalyst

I have a JSON file that I've added to the project's Resources/Raw/ folder and I have it marked as a MAUI Asset.

In the CSProj file I have:

```cs
<!-- Raw Assets (also remove the "Resources\Raw" prefix) -->
 <MauiAsset Include="Resources\Raw\**" LogicalName="%(RecursiveDir)%(Filename)%(Extension)" />

    <ItemGroup>
      <MauiAsset Update="Resources\Raw\ClientSecrets.json">
        <LogicalName>ClientSecrets.json</LogicalName>
        <CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory>
      </MauiAsset>
    </ItemGroup>
```

The code that I'm accessing the file with looks like this:

```cs
private GoogleCredential GetCredentialsFromFile()
        {
            GoogleCredential credential;

            using(var stream = new FileStream($"ClientSecrets.json", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
            {
                credential = GoogleCredential.FromStream(stream).CreateScoped(Scopes);
            }

            return credential;
        }
```

All of this works on iOS builds to virtual and physical devices, but the MacCatalyst build throws this error during runtime:

`Could not find file '/Users/kurt/Projects/Dirt_Wain_Compost_Logger/Dirt_Wain_Compost_Logger/bin/Debug/net7.0-maccatalyst/maccatalyst-x64/Dirt_Wain_Compost_Logger.app/ClientSecrets.json'.`

The build succeeds, the error is when I launch the program while debugging.

I have tried changing the filepath in the FileStream function to look for $"Contents/ClientSecrets.json" and it works for MacCataylst but then throws the same error for the iOS devices.

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?  I feel like there has to be a way to make it work for all platforms without making exceptions.

Thanks!!

Comment: Did you check if the file exists under that path on Mac?

Comment: Yes, it does.  I mentioned in my post that if I change the path to look in Contents/ for the Mac build it finds the file.  I’m just not convinced that I should have to look in different places for different build platforms.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whelp... it looks like I just didn't know about the .NET Maui Filesystem Helpers found here:

This did the trick

```
    public async Task<GoogleCredential> ReadTextFile(string filePath)
    {
        using (Stream fileStream = await FileSystem.Current.OpenAppPackageFileAsync(filePath))
        {
            GoogleCredential credential;
            credential = GoogleCredential.FromStream(fileStream).CreateScoped(Scopes);
            return credential;
        };
    }


    private GoogleCredential GetCredentialsFromFile()
    {
        GoogleCredential credential = ReadTextFile($"ClientSecrets.json").Result;

        return credential;
    }
```

The build is now working for iOS and Mac-Catalyst.

Comment: Excellent! You can refer to [Accept Your Own Answers](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/01/06/accept-your-own-answers/) as it's helpful to others facing the same problem! Thanks in advance!